# Can a CloudWatch Event in one region trigger a Lambda in another region of AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Can an AWS CloudWatch event in region `us-east-1` trigger a lambda in `us-west-2`? Or do I have to deploy my lambda in both regions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the dashboard, it is not possible to trigger cross region Lambda. When you create a CloudWatch event rule, select a `Target` to invoke, under Lambda function only the lambdas in the current region are shown.

[image]

Answer (score 16):

An alternative is to have CloudWatch trigger SNS. As per the attached screenshot, SNS topic subscription will allow full ARN declaration, and the dropdown even showed a us-east-1 lambda when I was in US West (Oregon) region.

[SNS Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyjRN.png)

Comment: that is not a bad idea but it does force me to change a few things mainly add another step in my pipeline.

Comment: SNS in the middle comes in handy quite often.  It's also nice for troubleshooting, because you can set yourself up temporarily as an email subscriber to the same topic, allowing you to see the events occurring and inspect their content, unobtrusively.

Comment: There are NO cross-region targets allowed. The screenshot shows just an example arn.
fyi: the new SNS Console does not allow to type ARNs by hand.

Comment: @f7o I think you are confusing Cloudwatch console where you choose an SNS topic to the SNS Console where you choose the Lambda ARN.

The above solution can be implemented like this - 
1) Create Lambda function in WEST.
2) Create SNS Topic in EAST and add WEST Lambda created above as the target.
3) Create CloudWatch event/alarm in US-EAST-1 that notifies the EAST SNS topic.

By doing this you are triggering a WEST Lambda from an EAST Cloudwatch Event/Alarm

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved by creating a the Event Rule in the source Region as well as SNS Topic in the same Region as a Target.

Then subscribe a Lambda in the target region to this SNS Topic.

Answer (score 0):

You may relay an event to a Eventbus in the desired region. There you can set an event rule to trigger the desired lambda.